# get params as object from http get angular

Tags: angularjs, spring

I have a service like this

```
$http.get(baseUrl + '/some', {
        params: {
            arg1: 1,
            arg2: 2
        }

    }).then(getSomeComplete).catch(getSomeFailed);
}
```

and constroller in spring like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Pto> getSomeage<SomeDDto(final SomeQuery someQuery) {

}
```

and SomeQuery

```
public class SomeQuery {

private int arg1;
private int arg2;

public SomeQuery() {
}

public SomeQuery(final int arg1, final int arg2) {
    this.arg1 = arg1;;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
}

public int getArg1() {
    return this.arg1;
}

public int getArg2() {
    return this.arg2;
}

}
```

when I get request in controller instead of value 1 and 2 in my object I have a zeros. Can I get params from http.get as object in controller?

Comment: Have you tried a `@RequestParam` annotation on `(final SomeQuery someQuery)`?

Comment: when I add @RequestParam I had conversion error. Could not convert string to SomeQuery

Comment: I see. If so, a `@RequestBody` annotation on your param should do the trick. You are POSTing the JSON object, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your java code looks fine and should work, you could try to load it from a browser (http://localhost:8080/some?arg1=1&arg2=2 or similar) and see the result.

I'm not familiar with angular and your problem may come from your `$http.get` call. May be the parameter names should be string ? try :

```
$http.get(baseUrl + '/some', {
        params: {
            'arg1': 1,
            'arg2': 2
        }

    }).then(getSomeComplete).catch(getSomeFailed);
}
```

Note the quotes around `arg1` and `arg2`